# ManyToMany Mapping In Hibernate Refers Wrong(Table name generated By api) Table Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hibernate @ManyToMany mapping Generates different *Join Table* Name and trying to fetch Data from that, which doesn't exist.

The join table defined  as "productcolumn_customfields" in `@JoinTable` mapping at entity, but it's expecting a different table and throwing the below

**error:**

> Table '**product_columns_details_customviews**' doesn't exist
>
> *Technologies used are:* Spring-boot, Spring-data-Jpa, Hibernate, MySql
>
> **Complete Error is:**
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.save(Unknown Source)     at
>   xxxx.ViewServiceImpl.insertViewNameService(ViewServiceImpl.java:564)
>     at
>   xxxx.ViewServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50dd8d1c.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>     at
>   xxxx.ViewServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1737579b.insertViewNameService()
>     at
>   xxxx.ViewController.insertViewNameController(ViewController.java:138)
>     at
>   xxxx.ViewController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d262cb92.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>     at
>   xxxx.ViewController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d8d1205.insertViewNameController()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:980)     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:290)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:850)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:832)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:468)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:202)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:176)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.merge(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.merge(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>     ... 139 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'xxx.product_columns_details_customviews' doesn't exist   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at

Custom-view Entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_views")
public class CustomViews implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7325379776348403853L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name="custom_id")
    private Long customId;

    @Column(name="view_name")
    private String viewName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "productcolumn_customfields", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cv_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "pcd_id",nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<ProductColumnsDetailsCV> productColumnsDetails;

    public CustomViews(){
        super();
    }

    public CustomViews(Long customId, String viewName, User user, List<ProductColumnsDetailsCV> productColumnsDetails) {
        super();
        this.customId = customId;
        this.viewName = viewName;
        this.user = user;
        this.productColumnsDetails = productColumnsDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customId
     */
    public Long getCustomId() {
        return customId;
    }

    /**
     * @param customId the customId to set
     */
    public void setCustomId(Long customId) {
        this.customId = customId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the viewName
     */
    public String getViewName() {
        return viewName;
    }

    /**
     * @param viewName the viewName to set
     */
    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productColumnsDetails
     */
    public List<ProductColumnsDetailsCV> getProductColumnsDetails() {
        return productColumnsDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @param productColumnsDetails the productColumnsDetails to set
     */
    public void setProductColumnsDetails(List<ProductColumnsDetailsCV> productColumnsDetails) {
        this.productColumnsDetails = productColumnsDetails;
    }

}
```

Product column Details Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_columns_details")
public class ProductColumnsDetailsCV implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7685428544522743567L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name="pid")
    private Long pid;

    @Column(name="display_name")
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name="column_name")
    private String columnName;

    @Column(name="actual_name")
    private String actualName;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name="is_pk")
    private boolean isPk;

    @Column(name="is_sortable")
    private boolean isSortable;

    @Column(name="order_")
    private int order;

    @Column(name="is_popup")
    private boolean isPopUp;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="productColumnsDetails")
    private List<CustomViews> customviews;


    public ProductColumnsDetailsCV() {
        super();
    }


    /**
     * @param pid
     * @param displayName
     * @param columnName
     * @param actualName
     * @param customFilter
     */
    public ProductColumnsDetailsCV(Long pid, String displayName, String columnName, String actualName) {

        this.pid = pid;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.actualName = actualName;
    }

    //Getters & Setter

}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `productcolumn_customfields` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pcd_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cv_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_pid_productcoldetails_idx` (`pcd_id`),
  KEY `id_cvid_customviews_idx` (`cv_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pcd_id_productcolumndet` FOREIGN KEY (`pcd_id`) REFERENCES `product_columns_details` (`pid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `id_cvid_customviews` FOREIGN KEY (`cv_id`) REFERENCES `custom_views` (`custom_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE `product_columns_details` (
  `pid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'String',
  `is_pk` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `is_sortable` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `order_` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_popup` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `actual_name_UNIQUE` (`actual_name`)

CREATE TABLE `custom_views` (
  `custom_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `view_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`custom_id`),
  KEY `custom_views_ibfk_1` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `custom_views_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user`enter code here`_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem happened because both side(in Entity) enforcing hibernate to do `many-to-many` mapping which is wrong. 
This is the resson hibernate is assuming the join table name is ***product_columns_details_customviews*** which doenot exists and not taking the table name from configuration(in annotation of Entity `CustomViews` ) i.e. ***productcolumn_customfields***

**Existing code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_columns_details")
public class ProductColumnsDetailsCV implements Serializable{
...
...
...
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name="productColumnsDetails")
private List<CustomViews> customviews;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_views")
public class CustomViews implements Serializable{
...
...
...
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "productcolumn_customfields", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cv_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "pcd_id",nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private List<ProductColumnsDetailsCV> productColumnsDetails;
```

**The only correction needed is :**

need to change entity mapping in **ProductColumnsDetailsCV**  as below.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy = "productColumnsDetails")
private List<CustomViews> customviews;
```

- Removed the annotation
  `@JoinColumn(name="productColumnsDetails")`
- Added attribute **mappedBy** in `@ManyToMany`

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying a joinColumn in one side and a joinTable in the other side, you need to remove the joinColumn from ProductColumnsDetailsCV

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
  private List<CustomViews> customviews;
```

Comment: Getting the same result even after removing joinColumn

Comment: why not let JPA create your tables ?

Comment: JPA should not create table in prod environemnt

Comment: @TheSprinter please try to remove '**' before and after the name of the join table name = "productcolumn_customfields", , also the first query which create your join table make it the last query not the first